# Azure repos in visual code return error with version

Tags: ionic-framework, tfs

When I have everything configured in Visual Code I get the following error:

[image]

But my version of TFS is 2017, has someone else happened this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to install Azure Repos Extension for Visual Studio Code? Which version of Visual Studio Code do you use?

Comment: I use version 1.46.1 of visual Code and version 1.125.159 of Azure Repos and I have TFS 2017, but it gives me an error that tells me that it is not compatible with version 2015 of TFS

Comment: Are the following items helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to install Azure Repos Extension for Visual Studio Code. First, you will need to install Visual Studio Code 1.12.0 or later.

Second, the extension uses your local repository information to connect to either Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 (and later). Please check whether the repository you open connected to appropriate TFS version.

Third, if you use TFVC, check whether you have the correct path of tf.exe.

Last, try to reinstall the extension and restart Visual Studio Code.